# Access Violation at avcodec_encode_video2()

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to understand the FFmpeg API by following online examples available but it seems that the FFmpeg API has changed over time, making most of the examples obsolete; I hope some of you can help me make more sense of the FFmpeg API examples.

I am currently trying to understand the [encoding-example](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/encoding-example_8c-source.html) from FFmpeg, but I am getting an Access Violation error at this line:

```
out_size = avcodec_encode_video2(codecCtx, &avpkt, picture, &got_packet);
```

where I get "Unhandled exception at 0x77c29e42 in test01_encode.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccc8." from Visual Studio.

I understand that *avcodec_encode_video()* is deprecated in favour of *avcodec_encode_video2()*, which uses AVPacket. I've allocated a buffer to data member of AVPacket and set its size, but still the same. What did I miss?

The library that I'm using is **ffmpeg-20160219-git-98a0053-win32-dev**. I would really really appreciate if you could help me out of this confusion.

(Side: What does it mean by "get delayed frames" and why are we encoding by specifying AVFrame* parameter as NULL?)

```
/*
 * Video encoding example
 */
char filename[] = "test.mpg";
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *codecCtx= NULL;
    int i, out_size, size, x, y, outbuf_size;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *picture;
    uint8_t *outbuf, *picture_buf;

    printf("Video encoding\n");

    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    /* find the mpeg1 video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    codecCtx= avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    picture= av_frame_alloc();

    /* put sample parameters */
    codecCtx->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    codecCtx->width = 352;
    codecCtx->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    //codecCtx->time_base= (AVRational){1,25};
    codecCtx->time_base.num = 1;
    codecCtx->time_base.den = 25;

    codecCtx->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
    codecCtx->max_b_frames=1;
    codecCtx->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(codecCtx, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fopen_s(&f,filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* alloc image and output buffer */
    outbuf_size = 100000;
    outbuf = (uint8_t*) malloc(outbuf_size);
    size = codecCtx->width * codecCtx->height;
    picture_buf = (uint8_t*) malloc((size * 3) / 2); /* size for YUV 420 */

    picture->data[0] = picture_buf;
    picture->data[1] = picture->data[0] + size;
    picture->data[2] = picture->data[1] + size / 4;
    picture->linesize[0] = codecCtx->width;
    picture->linesize[1] = codecCtx->width / 2;
    picture->linesize[2] = codecCtx->width / 2;

    picture->width = codecCtx->width;
    picture->height = codecCtx->height;
    picture->format = codecCtx->pix_fmt;

    AVPacket avpkt;
    int got_packet;

    avpkt.size=av_image_get_buffer_size(codecCtx->pix_fmt, codecCtx->width,
                    codecCtx->height,1);    
    avpkt.data = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(avpkt.size*sizeof(uint8_t));

    /* encode 1 second of video */
    for(i=0;i<25;i++) {
        fflush(stdout);
        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for(y=0;y<codecCtx->height;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<codecCtx->width;x++) {
                picture->data[0][y * picture->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }

        /* Cb and Cr */
        for(y=0;y<codecCtx->height/2;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<codecCtx->width/2;x++) {
                picture->data[1][y * picture->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                picture->data[2][y * picture->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }

        /* encode the image */
        //out_size = avcodec_encode_video(codecCtx, outbuf, outbuf_size, picture);
        // <Access violation> 
        out_size = avcodec_encode_video2(codecCtx, &avpkt, picture, &got_packet); 
        printf("encoding frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, out_size);
        //fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
        fwrite(avpkt.data, 1, avpkt.size, f);
    }

    /* get the delayed frames */
    for(; out_size; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);

        //out_size = avcodec_encode_video(codecCtx, outbuf, outbuf_size, NULL);
        out_size = avcodec_encode_video2(codecCtx, &avpkt, NULL, &got_packet); 
        printf("write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, out_size);
        //fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);
        fwrite(avpkt.data, 1, avpkt.size, f);
    }

    /* add sequence end code to have a real mpeg file */
    outbuf[0] = 0x00;
    outbuf[1] = 0x00;
    outbuf[2] = 0x01;
    outbuf[3] = 0xb7;
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, 4, f);
    fclose(f);
    free(picture_buf);
    free(outbuf);

    avcodec_close(codecCtx);
    av_free(codecCtx);
    av_free(picture);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Which line causes the error? And as you put `printf` statements there, could you share the output with us?

Comment: Hi @AntonSavin, the printf statemetn was never reached, as the exception occured just before it.

Comment: `printf("Video encoding\n");` isn't reached either?

Comment: Hi @Nacho, sorry, I was referring to the printf statement just after the _avcodec_encode_video2()_ function.

Comment: Well you have two different calls to that function, can you please edit your question stating the exact line that's giving the error? Hint, in the second function call you pass a NULL argument (here I feel the access violation occur) but I am not sure if you first set the `AV_CODEC_CAP_DELAY` mentioned in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__encoding.html#gaa2dc9e9ea2567ebb2801a08153c7306b)

Comment: 1) My bad. I have marked the offending line with a <Access violation> tag. 
2) The exception occurred on the first _avcodec_encode_video2()_ function call. 
3) I did see that in the documentation, but it's not used in the sample code provided on ffmpeg website.